# Follow someone using twitter Rest Api in R

Tags: r, rest, twitter

I am going through [this](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/friendships/create) documentation from twitter to follow someone.  I have authorized the account using the `twitteR` package with `api_key` , `access_token` etc. As this is a `POST` operation I decided to use `httr` package in R. One of the example provided in the documentation is

> https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json?user_id=1401881&follow=true

So accordingly , just changed the `user_id` to that of the account which I want to follow.

```
library(httr)
POST("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json?user_id=1401881&follow=true",verbose())
```

where `1401881` is the id which I want to follow.

This gives me

```
-> POST /1.1/friendships/create.json?user_id=1401881&follow=true HTTP/1.1
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.39.0 r-curl/0.9.1 httr/1.1.0
-> Host: api.twitter.com
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-> Cookie: guest_id=v1%3A146475568975546263
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> Content-Length: 0
-> 
<- HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
<- content-encoding: gzip
<- content-length: 87
<- content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
<- date: Wed, 01 Jun 2016 05:15:42 GMT
<- server: tsa_b
<- strict-transport-security: max-age=631138519
<- x-connection-hash: 6abd7db7f4c47058bf9d96e9ae23fb83
<- x-response-time: 5
<- 
Response [https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json? user_id=1401881&follow=true]
Date: 2016-06-01 05:15
Status: 400
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Size: 62 B
```

As can be seen in the response message it says `Bad Request` from which I believe the URL which I have generated is wrong. I also tried with

```
POST("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create", verbose(), 
    body = list(user_id = "101311381"), encode = "json")
```

I have tried various other ways and tried googling as well but cannot find a solution to this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you can only follow someone when that account also has authorized access of the api. This goes for everything for eg posting on any handle and other sort of things.

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli I was unable to do that in R. It was quite simple in Python though.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding your oauth_token (generated from the twitteR package) to the POST request

```
library(httr)
POST("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json?user_id=1401881&follow=true", 
           config(token = oauth_token))
```

Comment: What is `oauth_token` ? Is it the output generated from `setup_twitter_oauth` function?